# Inequality $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2y}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2z}} \leq \sqrt{3}$.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Recently I answered this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996338/for-the-given-function-fx-frac1-sqrt-1x-frac1-sqrt-1a-sqr/3998073#3998073) which required a proof for the upper and lower bound of a given function. While seemingly a calculus question, I realised that it can be transformed into an inequality problem, and my solution is detailed there. However, it seems that we can improve upon the upper bound substantially, from $2$ to $\sqrt{3}$. This leads us to the following claim:

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R^+},xyz=1$. Prove that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2y}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2z}} \leq \sqrt{3}$.

Equivalently, by the substitution $x=\dfrac{b}{a}, y=\dfrac{c}{b}, z=\dfrac{a}{c}$, it suffices for us to prove that for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a+2b}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{b}{b+2c}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{c}{c+2a}} \leq \sqrt{3}. $ But after thinking for a while, I still have no clue on how to proceed.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the question with the inequality as title instead of 'help in proving inequality' as i felt it would be more meaningful.I hope you are fine with that!

Comment: How about $x \to 0, y \to 0$?

Comment: That's right! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inequality doesn't true because the maximal value of k for which the inequality
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+kx}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+ky}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+kz}} \leqslant \frac{3}{\sqrt{k+1}},$$
is true for all positive real numbers $x,\,y,\,z$ satisfy $xyz=1$ is $k = \frac54.$

Comment: Yup, as @River Li has pointed out, my inequality is false. But you have made a very interesting point. Why is it $\dfrac{5}{4}$ in particular?

Comment: Let $x = \frac{bc}{a^2},\,y = \frac{ca}{b^2}, \, z = \frac{ab}{c^2}$ and choose $a = b = 1, \, c \to 0$ we get $k \leqslant \frac54.$ Finally, prove that the inequality also for $k = \frac54.$

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag could you share your proof for $k=5/4$?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore You can see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1900313p12993168).

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag thanks you!(+1)