# Showing $1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}<2$ for all positive real $a$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Gaokao Math-22, Jiangxi Province 2008:

> Define a function
> $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}}$$
> Prove that, for all positive real number $a$, $1<f(x)<2$.

I tried differentiating but the derivatives got too messy. Tried applying AM GM inequality too but in vain. I believe there lies a more elegant solution to the problem. I'
m out of ideas. Please also mention how you came up with the solution.

Comment: What is the domain for $x$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996338/for-the-given-function-fx-frac1-sqrt-1x-frac1-sqrt-1a-sqr/3998073#3998073

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646819/bounding-a-strange-function  ; there is at least one other posting as well, but the two in these comments may be the most helpful.  This appears to be an old contest problem that resurfaces here about every two years on average...

Comment: Surely it did. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One can prove non-strict inequality in a fairly straightforward way with multivariable calculus. This approach can be further enhanced to show the strict version, but it's less straightforward.

Let $x=b$ and $8/ax=c$.

Then the question is asking about behavior of  $f(a,b,c)=g(a)+g(b)+g(c)$ where $g(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}$ on domain $a,b, c\geq 0$ and subject to $abc=8$.

The gradient of $f$ is $(g'(a), g'(b), g'(c))$, while the gradient of the constraint is $(bc, ac,ba)=abc(
\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{c})$. Thus the critical point equations are

$$ag'(a)=bg'(b)=cg'(c).$$
The function $h(y)=-2 y g'(y)=y/(1+y)^{3/2}$  has $(1/h(y))^3=(1+y)/y^3=y^{-2}+y^{-3}$ monotone decreasing, so $h$ is monotone decreasing, so $h(a)=h(b)=h(c)$ implies $a=b=c$. So the only critical point of $f(a,b,c)$ is $a=b=c=2$. There the value is $\sqrt{3}$.

Now we need to study $f$ "at infinity" i.e. when one of the $a, b,c$ goes to infinity. Then, since $abc=8$ one of the others goes to $0$. The value is then limiting to something in between $1$ and $2$.

More precisely, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is  $R(\epsilon)$ such that outside of triangle $a+b+c<R(\epsilon)$ the function $f(a,b,c)$ is bounded between $1-\epsilon$ and $2+\epsilon$. Thus it is also so bounded on any triangle $a+b+c\leq R$  when $R>R(\epsilon)$ (maximum and minimum are attained by compactness, and can either be attained at the boundary or at the unique interior critical point; in either case they are between $1-\epsilon$ and $2+\epsilon$). Thus  $1-\epsilon <f<2+\epsilon$ everywhere, and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary $1\leq f\leq 2$.

Remark: Fixing $ab=8/c$ and doing 1-D constrained optimization that way, one gets $a=b$ at the unique critical point. This easily yields $1<f$, but getting  $f<2$, while possible in this approach requires (as far as I can tell) some somewhat subtle arguments about the behavior near infinity.